# How to convert an ASCII char to its ASCII int value?

Tags: c++, arduino

I would like to convert a char to its [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) int value.

I could fill an array with all possible values and compare to that, but it doesn't seems right to me. I would like something like

```
char mychar = "k"
public int ASCItranslate(char c)
return c   

ASCItranslate(k) // >> Should return 107 as that is the ASCII value of 'k'.
```

The point is `atoi()` won't work here as it is for readable numbers only.

It won't do anything with spaces (ASCII 32).

Comment: Did you try anything? Like, for example, `return c;`?

Comment: `char mychar = "k"`: Oh heavens, have you tried this? `"k"` is a null-terminated string, not a `char`. Also, `C++` statements have to end with a semi-colon. Surely you know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:-

```
char mychar = 'k';
//and then
int k = (int)mychar;
```

Comment: Won't work on machines using [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC). If portability is desired, something more complicated is required.

Comment: EBCDIC isnt ASCI, EBCDIC is older was only used by IBM in their earlier systems. i remember even the MSX had ASCI so this must be real old, i use it on a Arduino which understands it.

Comment: Why is this upvoted/accepted? It's not even valid code.

Answer (score 22):

Just do this:

```
int(k)
```

You're just converting the char to an int directly here, no need for a function call.

Answer (score 7):

A `char` is already a number. It doesn't require any conversion since the ASCII is just a mapping from numbers to character representation.

You could use it directly as a number if you wish, or cast it.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, you could also use `static_cast<int>(k)` to make the conversion explicit.

Comment: Casting is always explicit. Using a cast makes a **conversion** explicit. Of course, in almost all cases the compiler will do the conversion anyway, and the cast is just noise.

Comment: I meant "explicit to the programmer", not to the compiler.

Comment: Nevertheless, it's the **conversion** that is made explicit. A **cast** is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion; casts are **always** explicit.

Comment: OK, got it :) I have fixed my sentence.

Answer (score 1):

To Convert from an **ASCII character** to it's **ASCII value**:

```
  char c='A';
    cout<<int(c);
```

To Convert from an **ASCII Value** to it's **ASCII Character**:

```
int a=67;
  cout<<char(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

char mychar = 'k';
int ASCIItranslate(char ch) {
    return ch;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << ASCIItranslate(mychar);
    return 0;
}
```

That's your original code with the various syntax errors fixed. Assuming you're using a compiler that uses ASCII (which is pretty much every one these days), it works. Why do you think it's wrong?